# How to set ImageView to apply image size to screen resolution in Android

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I have an application that uses ImageViews to show some pictures. The image sizes are 320x480px.
I use some animation to move these pictures to the center of the screen and when the phone has the resolution of 320x480, it works great.

However, when I tried it on emulator with the resolution of 240*320, there were some problems:

- The ImageView is still 320x480 so it looks way too big
- The animation that uses the screen resolution can't move the pictures to the center, it is at least 20-30 px off

I learned the when dealing with pictures, Android dynamically changes resolution of them to make the images fit in. How could I set that these images should be resized according to screen resolution?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's wrong without seeing any code. Android resizes images from `res/drawable` according your screen resolution (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, etc.). If you place pictures in `res/drawable-nodpi`, they will **not** be scaled. You could also use the density dependent folders `res/drawable-ldpi`, `res/drawable-mdpi`, `res/drawable-hdpi` etc. You should definitely read the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` and  `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` is what I needed. The ImageViews are scaled *down* to 240x320 and the animation works well. 
Interesting that the upscaling is not proper. When I used in the emulator at 480x800, my ImageView is scaled up to 480x720 so I get black edges. Any idea for that?